# How to pass date from Php date variable to javascript date variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hello i need to get this date value from php 1328569380 and convert it to javascript date.
By the way how is this date "1328569380" type of form called ?

Comment: the "type of form" looks like its the php strtotime function performed on a date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The numeric date time your are referring to is called a timestamp. It is the number of seconds elapsed since january 1st of 1970 if i'm not wrong.

To send a date to javascript, just print it out using the timestamp x 1000 since it also accepts millisecond initialization format:

```
mydate = new Date(<?php echo $mytimestamp*1000; ?>);
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

This is a Unix epoch timestamp. See the following thread for the how-to:

[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Your value is the number of seconds that has passed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, called the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

JavaScript counts the number of milliseconds instead, thus you have to multiply your timestamp with 1000 prior to using it to create a JavaScript date-object.

```
var phptimestamp = 1328569380;
var date = new Date(phptimestamp * 1000);
```